# IE11: Bootstrap columns not behaving properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to make my website IE11 compatible.

I have 2 columns inside a row, which both should have different heights.
I have tried with

```
height:auto;
```

This works great in chrome but not in IE11. It renders like this:
[image]

The right one is IE11, I want it to behave like Chrome where the form box is fitted to its content. I have attached my full code below, it might be messy so beware.

```css
html {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; }

body {
  margin: 0px;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%; }

.form-popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%; }

.content-wrapper {
  margin: 0 2%; }

.content-wrapper > * {
  margin: auto; }

.page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

.page-wrapper--bg-cover {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; }

.form-wrapper {
  height: auto !important;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-rows: auto 12px auto 12px auto 12px auto 12px auto 12px auto;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 12px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 40px; }
  @media all and (max-width: 576px) {
    .form-wrapper {
      grid-template-rows: 2fr repeat(2, 1fr); } }
  @media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .form-wrapper {
      grid-template-rows: 2fr repeat(2, 1fr); } }

.name-input {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 12px;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 12px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); }
  .name-input input {
    border: none;
    background: none; }
  @media all and (max-width: 576px) {
    .name-input {
      -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
      -ms-grid-rows: 1fr 12px 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr; } }
  @media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .name-input {
      -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
      -ms-grid-rows: 1fr 12px 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr; } }

.name-field {
  padding: 13px;
  padding-top: 10.5px;
  padding-bottom: 10.5px;
  background-color: #f4f7f6;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%; }
  .name-field input {
    width: 100%; }

.name-field--column1 {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-row: 1; }
  @media all and (max-width: 576px) {
    .name-field--column1 {
      -ms-grid-column: 1;
      -ms-grid-row: 1; } }
  @media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .name-field--column1 {
      -ms-grid-column: 1;
      -ms-grid-row: 1; } }

.name-field--column3 {
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  -ms-grid-row: 1; }
  @media all and (max-width: 576px) {
    .name-field--column3 {
      -ms-grid-column: 1;
      -ms-grid-row: 3; } }
  @media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .name-field--column3 {
      -ms-grid-column: 1;
      -ms-grid-row: 3; } }

.name-field--has-label {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 25px auto;
  grid-template-columns: 25px auto; }

.email-field {
  padding: 13px;
  padding-top: 10.5px;
  padding-bottom: 10.5px;
  background-color: #f4f7f6;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%; }
  .email-field input {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    width: 100%; }

.email-field--has-label {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 25px auto;
  grid-template-columns: 25px auto; }

.phone-field {
  padding: 13px;
  padding-top: 10.5px;
  padding-bottom: 10.5px;
  background-color: #f4f7f6;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%; }
  .phone-field input {
    background: none;
    border: none; }

.phone-field--has-label {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 25px auto;
  grid-template-columns: 25px auto; }

.school-field {
  padding: 13px;
  padding-top: 10.5px;
  padding-bottom: 10.5px;
  background-color: #f4f7f6;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%; }
  .school-field input {
    background: none;
    border: none; }

.school-field--has-label {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 25px auto;
  grid-template-columns: 25px auto; }

.submit-button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%; }

.submit-button__button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #7edcff;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 13px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 14px 0 rgba(126, 220, 255, 0.44);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 14px 0 rgba(126, 220, 255, 0.44); }

.example-download {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  margin: 13px auto; }

.example-download__text {
  display: inherit;
  margin: auto 2px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.15;
  color: #878787; }

.example-download__link {
  display: inherit;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto 2px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.15;
  color: #7edcff;
  text-decoration: underline; }

.ideal-box {
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.15;
  padding-top: 46px; }
  @media all and (max-width: 576px) {
    .ideal-box {
      text-align: center; } }
  .ideal-box:before {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    content: "";
    width: 200px;
    border-top: 12px solid #000000;
    top: 0;
    left: 15px; }

.ideal-box__header {
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-size: 36px; }

.ideal-box__header--bold {
  font-weight: bold; }

.headline {
  margin: 0 auto 58px; }

.headline__teacher {
  max-width: 750px;
  font-size: 58px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-align: center; }

.headline__teacher--bold {
  font-weight: bold; }

.headline__teacher--centered {
  margin: 0 auto; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script src=" https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js " integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN "
        crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js " integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q "
        crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js " integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl "
        crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js "></script>
    <meta name="viewport " content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 ">
    <title>Start Trial</title>
</head>

<body class="page-wrapper page-wrapper--bg-cover align-items-center " style="background:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(251,
        238, 229,0.9),rgba(251, 238, 229,0.9)),url(/img/webpnet-compress-image.jpg); ">
    <header>
        <nav class="nav ">

        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="form-popup" style="display:none;">HEJ GRIMME!</div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row headline">
            <h1 class="headline__teacher headline__teacher--bold headline__teacher--centered">Lærer: Prøv QTI på dig selv</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row content-wrapper justify-content-between">
            <div class="ideal-box col-12 col-md-4">
                <h2 class="ideal-box__header ideal-box__header--bold">Skab din egen idealprofil</h2>
                <p>Prøv QTI på dig selv helt gratis! Udfyld kontaktformularen, så sender vi dig&nbsp;et link til den del af
                    QTI-testen, der handler om din ideale QTI-profil.</p>
                <p>Når du har besvaret de 32 spørgsmål om, hvordan du gerne vil lede din klasse,&nbsp;udarbejder vi din ideal&nbsp;QTI-profil
                    og sender den til dig.</p>
                <p>Den fulde QTI-test, som din uddannelsesinstitution&nbsp;skal købe licens til, indeholder også besvarelse
                    af spørgsmålene ud fra, hvordan du opfatter dit samspil med en bestemt klasse, og hvordan&nbsp;dine elever
                    opfatter dig som klasseleder.</p>
                <p>Ved køb af licens skal to af&nbsp;de pædagogiske ledere på din uddannelsesinstitution gennemføre et certificeringskursus.
                    Certificeringen sikrer dig en kvalificeret udviklingsdialog med din leder og er samtidig din garanti
                    for en etisk forsvarlig brug af QTI.</p>
            </div>
            <form class="form-wrapper col-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="name-input">
                    <div class="name-field name-field--has-label name-field--column1">
                        <label style="margin: 0 auto;" style="-ms-grid-column: 1; -ms-grid-row: 1;">
                            <i class="far fa-user"></i>
                        </label>
                        <input type="name" name="Firstname" placeholder="Fornavn" style="-ms-grid-column:
        3; -ms-grid-row: 1;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="name-field name-field--column3">
                        <input type="name" name="Lastname" placeholder="Efternavn">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="email-field email-field--has-label " style="-ms-grid-row: 3;">
                    <label style="margin: 0 auto;" style="-ms-grid-column: 1; -ms-grid-row: 1;">
                        <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                    </label>
                    <input type="email" required placeholder="E-mail" style="width:100%; -ms-grid-column: 3; -ms-grid-row:
        1;" name="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="phone-field phone-field--has-label " style="-ms-grid-row: 5; ">
                    <label style="margin: 0 auto; height:16px; " style="-ms-grid-column: 1; -ms-grid-row: 1; ">
                        <i class="fas fa-phone " data-fa-transform="rotate-90 "></i>
                    </label>
                    <input maxlength="8" type="tel" placeholder="Telefon" style="width:100%; -ms-grid-column: 3; -ms-grid-row:
        1;">
                </div>
                <div class="school-field school-field--has-label " style="-ms-grid-row: 7; ">
                    <label style="margin: 0 auto; height:16px; " style="-ms-grid-column: 1; -ms-grid-row: 1; ">
                        <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap "></i>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Skole" style="width:100%; -ms-grid-column: 3; -ms-grid-row: 1;">
                </div>
                <div class="submit-button" style="-ms-grid-row: 9;">
                    <input class="submit-button__button" type="submit" value="Send">
                </div>
                <div class="example-download" style="-ms-grid-row: 11;">
                    <p class="example-download__text" style="-ms-grid-column: 1;">Se eksempel på en QTI-profil-rapport</p>
                    <a class="example-download__link" style="-ms-grid-column: 2;" href="https://qti.dk/files/4/qti-profil.pdf">
                        Download PDF
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    $('document').ready(function() {
        $('.form-wrapper').submit(function() {
            $('.form-popup').toggle(1000);
            return false;
        })
    })
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you even bother using Bootstrap? I mean, you are using almost **nothing** of what Bootstrap provides... If you do almost everything with custom css, then Bootstrap becomes kinda pointless, doesn't it? It shouldn't be a surprise when things break if you do it that way. If you replace all those parts of your custom css that can be handled with Bootstrap, if you replaced that with Bootstrap classes, then all of your issues will just disappear. No need to worry about Browser compatibility in that case.

Comment: Bootstrap just isn't designed to be broken with custom css hacks like that. When you use Bootstrap, you should only use custom css for the very rare things that Bootstrap can't handle with native classes.

Comment: I mean, in the olden days of Bootstrap 3 things were different, but with Bootstrap 4 you can do almost everything you need with native classes.

Comment: I ditched bootstrap and now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by not using bootstrap in the first place